# Averaging multiple netCDF files to produce one raster

Tags: r, raster, arcgis, netcdf

I realize this appears to be simple but I cannot figure it out.

I have 120 netCDF files, each with the daily minimum temperature for a year for Australia. For example, file "mintemp_2000.nc" is a netCDF with 365 bands where each band is the min temperature for each day of that year.

I want to "combine" all those netCDF files (across years) so I have a single raster, where each pixel is the average min temp over the 120-year period.

I'd like to stick with R or ArcGIS Pro if possible as those are the two I'm somewhat familiar with.

I've also noticed in ArcGIS that temp values are missing for some days in the year and am concerned with how these blank values will influence the average.

Thank you!

I tried to use CDO on my mac (my first time using homebrew) but the outputs made zero sense (for example parts had an average min temp of 230°C) and I was having major issues with projecting the raster output (.tiff) in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: CDO should be able to handle this problem free. If it’s giving you strange output you most likely have data formatting issues

Comment: I looked at some of the .nc files in ArcMap and they look good.
The code I used was: cdo ensmean file/mintemp*.nc mintemp.tiff
How I can I tell if there are formatting issues, aside from visual inspection of all 120 .nc files in Arc?

Comment: Try “cdo -fldmax-mergetime file/mintemp*nc out.nc”, and view the output. That will give you the spatial maximum per year. This might identify files with problems

Comment: This site is for asking specific coding questions. Always show what you have tried, and where possible include some data or a link to the data. For GIS questions you can go to gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

With R, you should be able to do that like this

```
# use 
# ff <- list.files(pattern="nc$")
# to get something like this
ff <- c("mintemp_2000.nc", "mintemp_2001.nc", "mintemp_2002.nc")

library(terra)
r <- rast(ff)
m <- mean(r)
```